# What happens if my LCD desktop monitor is detected as a 'Laptop'?

Tags: 12.04, monitor

Since I plugged in my new Acer TFT ubuntu 12.04 detects it as "Laptop". But it's a Acer S231HL. Can you help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a minor bug which **does not affect the operation** of your monitor or system in any way. It should hopefully be fixed via an update in the near future.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: @EliahKagan, here's [one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/970560) for `gnome-desktop`, but I'm positive there is/was one filed against X and another one (or maybe the former again) referencing Nvidia drivers.